# Ring of quotients: find number of elements in $Q(\mathbb{Z}_4,\{1,3\})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Ring of quotients: find number of elements in $Q(\mathbb{Z}_4,\{1,3\})$

I don't even know what to do here. From what I read in my book I'm not sure what I am supposed to really be doing. I gathered as much as I take $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \{1,3\}$ and construct a field of quotients.

so the direct product yields the possibilities $(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(0,3),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)$

Comment: What is the notation $Q(\mathbb Z_4, \{1,3\})$?

Comment: My guess is that you want $S^{-1}R$ for $R = \mathbb Z_4$ and $S = \{1, 3\}$. You already have the direct product $R \times S$. Try to find the required equivalence classes.

Comment: Alternatively, just note that $3$ is already a unit in $\mathbb Z_4$...

Comment: Assuming what @AymanHourieh said is the question, you can prove more general results: Let $R$ be a ring and let $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $R$ consisting of units only (need not be the all of the units). Then $S^{-1}R \cong R.$ (The idea here is when you are "inverting" elements which are already invertible, you won't get anything more.)